# R error "can't combine <character> and <double>?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having an issue with a dataset that my team and I are working on. When trying to `mutate` a few variables into a new variable (named `EU`) here, this error pops up saying:

```
[Error: Problem with 'mutate()` input `EU`.
x Can't combine `...` <character> and `..2` <double>.]
```

I should note that my team and I all get this issue, but not always in the same part of the script. We've all updated our software to match and it still seems to happen.

Does anyone know how to fix this?? Thank you for any suggestions! We are learning as we go :)

Comment: Your post is likely to get a downvote if you don't provide a reproducible example, but entries in the column of a data frame in R need to be of the same class. They all need to be character strings, all need to be numeric, etc.

Comment: Hi Alice, please share that piece of code and some data that allow us to run your code. PS: in order to use the same version of every package, check out the library `packrat`. It's great to work in team.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm afraid it's a huge dataset and im not sure which part exactly has the problem in it. I'm new and not sure what I'm able to share..  Thank you @Rstudious for that info, we'll have a closer look at it.

Comment: @Edo we'll try packrat! Thanks! I might add more information to this as I know a bit more

Comment: try to share `dput(head(your_dataframe))` and the code that calls mutate. It may be enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your post to include a sample of the datasets.  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr")

Comment: @Edo we ended up using renv instead of packrat, seems to be a more stable replacement to packrat, thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you @itsMeInMiami unfortunately I'm not able to share any data. Sorry for not adding more to the post! I wasn't aware it would be necessary but now I of course understand why. But I appreciate all the helpful comments!

Answer (score 1):

#### Reproducing the problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(col = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"))
df2 <- tibble(col = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
bind_rows(df1, df2)

Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1$col` <character> and `..2$col` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

#### Explanation

The error occurs when you are trying to combine a column of character-type values (e.g. `"hello world"`) with a column of double-type values (e.g. `100`).

#### Solution

Find the offending column(s), and either drop them, or convert them so they're both in the same format:

```
df3 <- tibble(col = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

df3 %>% 
  mutate(col = as.numeric(col)) %>% 
  bind_rows(df2) # works, returns a column of doubles

df2 %>% 
  mutate(col = as.character(col)) %>%
    bind_rows(df3) # works, returns a column of characters
```

#### Finding non-matching columns

The following function finds the columns in df1 which are in df2, but don't have the same column type:

```
compare_df_col_types <- function(df1, df2) {
  t1 <- df1 %>% 
    map_df(class) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "df1_cols", values_to = "df1_class")
    t2 <- df2 %>%
    map_df(class) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "df2_cols", values_to = "df2_class")
    comparison <- t1 %>%
        left_join(t2, by = c("df1_cols" = "df2_cols")) %>%
        filter(df1_class != df2_class)
    return(comparison)
}
```